# Is it possible to emit data from node/socket to 2 clients at the same time?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am using emit to send a large amount of data ~1mb when a client connects. For some reason I expected it to not matter how many clients did this at once but now I see that I was likely wrong. It seems that the second client must wait until the first client receives all of the data to start receiving theirs.  Is this right and is there any way around it?

```
var moment = require('moment');

var connect = require('connect'),
    socketio = require('socket.io'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    connectionsArray    = [],
    connection          = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 50,
        host        : '127.0.0.1',
        user        : 'root',
        password    : '',
        database    : 'hideout',
        port        : 3306
    }),
    POLLING_INTERVAL = 500,
    pollingTimer;

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var server = connect(
  connect.static(__dirname + '/public')
).listen(port);

var io = socketio.listen(server);

function initializeDatabase(){
    orders=[];
    var query2 = connection.query('SELECT open_orders.*,categories.`parent` as parent FROM `open_orders` LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.`id`=open_orders.`category` WHERE `item_parent` IS NULL AND `void` IS NULL ORDER BY `table`,`timestamp`');
    query2
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log( err );
        updateSocket( err );

    })
    .on('result', function( order ) {
        var theDatetime = moment(order.datetime).format();
        var order_item = {
            "id":order.id,
            "cover":order.cover,
            "table_number":order.table,
            "seat":order.seat,
            "name":order.name,
            "price":order.price,
            "item_parent":order.item_parent,
            "category":order.category,
            "non_taxable":order.non_taxable,
            "parent":order.parent,
            "datetime":theDatetime,
            "op_pin":order.op_pin,
            "timestamp":order.timestamp,
            "menu_id":order.menu_id,
            "mod_group_id":order.mod_group_id,
            "mod_required":order.mod_required,
            "check":order.check,
            "split_parent":order.split_parent,
            "sent":order.sent,
            "complete":order.complete,
            "mods":[]
        };
        orders.push(order_item);
    })
    .on('end',function(){
    });
}
initializeDatabase();

function ordersView(socket){
    updateSocket(socket, {orders:orders});
}

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) {
    console.log('Number of connections:' + connectionsArray.length);

    socket.on('tablesView', function(){
        ordersView(socket);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf( socket );
        console.log('socket = ' + socketIndex + ' disconnected');
        if (socketIndex >= 0) {
            connectionsArray.splice( socketIndex, 1 );
        }
    });

    console.log( 'A new socket is connected!' );
    connectionsArray.push( socket );
});

var updateSocket = function ( socket, data ) {
    data.time = moment(new Date()).format();
    socket.emit( 'notification' , data );
};

var updateSockets = function ( socket, data ) {
    data.time = moment(new Date()).format();
    connectionsArray.forEach(function( tmpSocket ){
        if(tmpSocket!==socket){
            tmpSocket.volatile.emit( 'notification' , data );
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: No, that's not right. Can you show how you implemented sending the data? Also, knowing about the background of your system: are all your clients using the same (wireless) network?

Comment: if possible, show us the basic implementation of the serverside.

Comment: Okay - thank you for taking a look.  I scaled my code back to the smallest possible to get to the problem and added it to this post.

Comment: Are you wanting to send the data to all connected clients? You would use `io.emit()` for that

Comment: In this case, it is just the client that sends 'tablesView' per the below code:

socket.on('tablesView', function(){
      ordersView(socket);
});

Comment: I think it may be an issue with clients saturating the network. Have you tried to add a limit to the # of records being returned from the query to see if that helps concurrency?